# Comparing Dataframe with different structures

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes with columns as below:

df1 =
a         b     c    d           e
orange    7     21   high       sweet
apple     9     44   very high  sweet
lemon     3     13   low        sour

df2 =

a         b     c
orange    7     21
apple     9     44

Now, I want to create a new dataframe, say df3 that has values in df2 that are also in df1 but in the structure of df1

So, as per the above example, the new dataframe will be

df3 =

a         b     c    d           e
orange    7     21   high       sweet
apple     9     44   very high  sweet

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply use `merge`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This does an inner join, keeping only rows that all three columns [a,b,c] exists in both dataframes, and will also have all of df1 extra columns.

Note that this will work for you example. If there are more columns in either of the dataframes, they will appear in the final result, so this will have to go through some adjustments.